# Which files should I validate on an image upload feature?

Tags: security-testing

I'm curious which files I should be checking for on a typical image upload feature. This particular one I'm testing is for a profile picture.

Things I'm already checking for:

- Image file size (e.g. < 1MB)
- Image dimensions (e.g. 200x200 pixels or less)
- Image file extensions only (e.g. png/jpg/jpeg/gif etc)
- Image Mime types only (e.g. `image/png`)

Are there any other common things to check for with this? I feel like I might be forgetting to check for some important security issue. The file extension and mime types cover most issues I can think of.

Comment: "Image Mime types only (e.g. image/png)" what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needs to consider the following also

1. Verify by adding a file or a pdf should throw invalid file format error message
2. Verify if drag and drop functionality is working or not
3. Verify drag and drop multiple image files
4. verify once a new pic is uploaded the old pic should not display anywhere
5. Verify the image upload functionality in mobile devices.